# TypeScript error: Comparison on enum values apparently will "always return false" even though all types exist on the enum

Tags: typescript

I have an enum:

```js
export enum AggregateFunction {
  NONE,
  TOTAL,
  AVG,
  MIN,
  MAX,
  COUNT
}
```

And I have conditional code depending on the value of a provided `AggregateFunction` value:

```js
import { AggregateFunction } from './Condition'

...
  const compare = (aggregateFunction: AggregateFunction | null = null) => {

    // Make sure it's not null
    if (! aggregateFunction) {
      throw new Error(`AggregateFunction must be defined`)
    }

    // This first statement flags a typescript error
    if (aggregateFunction === AggregateFunction.NONE) {
      //
    }
    else if (aggregateFunction === AggregateFunction.TOTAL) {
      //
    }
    else if (aggregateFunction === AggregateFunction.AVG) {
      //
    }
    else if (aggregateFunction === AggregateFunction.MIN) {
      //
    }
    else if (aggregateFunction === AggregateFunction.MAX) {
      //
    }
    else if (aggregateFunction === AggregateFunction.COUNT) {
      //
    }
  }
```

For the comparison of `AggregateFunction.NONE` I am getting the following TypeScript error:

```
This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'AggregateFunction.TOTAL | AggregateFunction.AVG | AggregateFunction.MIN | AggregateFunction.MAX | AggregateFunction.COUNT' and 'AggregateFunction.NONE' have no overlap.
```

How is it possible that only this first enum type flags this error? Based on the error code, it is acting like the `NONE` type is not part of the enum at all?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript is catching a particularly insidious bug for you:

```
if (!aggregateFunction) {
     throw new Error(`AggregateFunction must be defined`)
}
```

will throw on `AggregateFunction.NONE` because it equals `0`. Instead use:

```
if (aggregateFunction === null) {
    throw new Error(`AggregateFunction must be defined`)
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's a sneaky one. I've updated my enum to have specific values now e.g. `NONE = "NONE"` just to be safe. Works like a charm! Much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, coming back to this briefly: would this not evaluate my expression to `if (0 === 0)`, which is perfectly valid?

Comment: @Ollie I don't understand your question

Comment: I understand your explanation of the first error and that `AggregateFunction.NONE` will equal `0` at runtime so it might get caught by the error. But in regards to the second part where I compare `if(aggregateFunction === AggregateFunction.NONE)`, would this not simply evaluate to `if(aggregateFunction === 0)`, which is a perfectly valid comparison?

Comment: @Ollie This is a perfectly valid comparison but it will never be true, so the code is redundant. That is why typescript warns you. It will never be true because the code will throw before it is ever evaluated.

Comment: Ahh finally I get it! Makes perfect sense now. Thank you so much